# Not able to read multiple block in NFCISO15693Tag using CoreNFC framework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc, core-nfc

Steps

1. I have created provision profile which support NFC.
2. Enable NFC in entitlements file.
3. Add NFC description in info.plist file.

Now I am getting its NFCISO15693Tag kind of tag I am getting system information.
While I am trying to read multiple block. Always I am getting tag connection error.

```
session.connect(to: iso93tag, completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in
if error == nil {
iso93.readMultipleBlocks(requestFlags: .highDataRate, blockRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: 4))
        { data, error in
        }
}
}
```

[NFCTagReaderSession transceive:tagUpdate:error:]:824  Error Domain=NFCError Code=100 "Tag connection lost" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Tag connection lost}

Comment: You only have seven lines of code to read an NFC tag?

Comment: 1. No I have other code but but I didn't mention it because its too long.